# How to remove time from the date format?

Tags: javascript, datetime, ecmascript-6

I am trying to remove time from the date format which is coming from the backend , what is correct approach to achieve this task? Its not a date object.

main.js

```
const date = "2020-08-05 00:08:00 "
console.log(date.split[0];
```

should output (but it is not happening):

```
"2020-08-05"
```

Comment: It seems you answered your own question, no?

Comment: not happening with the code i have

Comment: How is it not happening? It sure looks like it's working.

Comment: I took the liberty to "clarify" your question from my understanding... If it is not correct, click "edit" and roll back to the previous version.

Comment: You need to specify a delimiter for split, so simply `date.split(" ")[0]` will work (basically what @alvaro posted below).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Or `date.substring(0,10)`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should split by blank space and then get the first element, remember that `split` is a function.

```js
const date = "2020-08-05 00:08:00 "
console.log(date.split(" ")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex as date format will be the same always.

```js
const date = '2020-08-05 00:08:00 ';
const ret = date.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/);
console.log(ret[0]);
```